# Can we get tweets for last 4 months... suppose I am pulling tweets in April.. is there any way to get all the tweets since 1st Jan to 1st april ??

Tags: r, search, twitter, tweetstream

Can we get tweets for last 4 months... suppose I am pulling tweets in April.. is there any way to get all the tweets since 1st Jan to 1st april?

I tried using below command but I am not getting tweets since Jan..

tweets <- searchTwitter ("India", n=10000, since="2015-01-01", lang="en")